# How to use IdentityServer4 to authenticate local user from local database?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm creating SSO solution for multiple existing projects. Most of the applications already use same database, so same users and I use these users in IdentityServer. But there is one app which has its own users DB and login screen. Users from this table are used in one of the tables in this app (FK).

My idea is to leave existing users DB as is. Add a column `MasterUserGuid` to `Users` table that will contain "master" user Guid (so the user that IdentityServer uses for authentication) and implement following flow:

1. User opens the app and is not signed in
2. User is redirected to IdentityServer and uses global credentials
3. User is redirected back to the app which gets global user GUID from claims and authenticates local user (with this GUID in the `MasterUserGuid` column), instead of using global user

The problem is that I don't know how to implement step `3` or if it's even possible/supported in IdentityServer4. At the moment I'm redirected to IdentityServer, am authenticated and redirected back, but then the app tries to use this external user.

While researching I've read that users should be in one table, so maybe  this approach is totally wrong and it would be better to remove local users and break FK for mentioned table and do some manual migration of users.

Is the scenario described in the steps I provided possible and sane?

Comment: first of all, what your *one app* is? is that ASP.NET classic (owin), ASP.NET Core, does it use MS Identity FW to access the db?

Comment: It's ASP.NET Core MVC using EntityFramework. Currently it uses `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` to auth against this local DB.

Comment: From what I see (I haven't written this app) AspNet.Identity uses same context (`app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>((options, context) => ApplicationUserManager.Create(context.Get<ModelEntities>()));` where `ModelEntities` is EF context class. Identity uses standard set of tables in the DB (`AspNetRoles`, `AspNetUsers` etc) which are not mapped as `IDbSet`s in the context.

Comment: I'm thinking now that the solution may be to let the user be authenticated with global user, but find and override places where UserID is used, to use the mapping column and local user ID instead of global one. I'll check now if this makes sense in the code.

Comment: first i'd get rid of AspNet.Identity. then in `AddAuthentication.AddOpenIdConnect` adjust the local token to keep whatever you like as the primary identity (within the app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your application to authenticate via IdentityServer first. Remove all the ASP.NET Core Identity logic related to registration, login etc. assuming all of that will be done on IdentityServer side. Then implement the instance of `IClaimsTransformation` which will either replace your current `ClaimsPrincipal`or add additional identities to it if needed with the claim values you want (populated from local database). Here is the example:

```cs
public class MyClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(...)); // put here your claim type and value

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
        principal.AddIdentity(identity);
        return principal;
    }
}
```

Then register your claims transformer in IOC in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, MyClaimsTransformer>();
```